# css link change every day automatically

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a file with same css link to change every day at 12 midnight. my file link is like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php $filelocation->fetchdir($css); ?>blue.css">
```

I want to `blue.css` to change next week to `green.css` and the following week `yellow.css` and then the circle will start over again

How can I do this? please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store your colors in an array, then get the current timestamp and divide it by 7 days. Then get modulo of the result and you're done:

```
<?php
// (...)
$colors = array('blue', 'green', 'yellow');
$chosenColor = intval(time() / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) % count($colors); // 60 seconds, 60 minutes, 24 hours, 7 days, 3 color variants

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $filelocation->fetchdir($css) . $colors[$chosenColor]; ?>.css">
```

Depending on what color you want to show on what week, change their order in the array.

*Note: When you opened the php tag in the `href` attribute, you used `<?php`. Assuming that you wanted to output the result, I changed it to `<?=` which is exactly the same as `<? echo`.*

Comment: Thanks matewka and sorry for my late reply but will this change the color on its own? because I remember an issue like this which happened when someone refresh the page the time starts again. I dont want that to happen. I want the server to know the minute I upload  this code is when the time starts

Comment: I used here the `time()` function. It receives the current timestamp from the server, as I stated in the answer.

Comment: sorry bad eye. Your code doesn't work thats the only issues. i did `echo` and still nothing

Comment: Ziollek works works. I wasn't too sure of the `'W'` so i replace it with ` switch(time() / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7) % 12)` and this works but will this change every week?

Comment: the issue i think is to do with `$colors[$chosenColor]`

Comment: Check it again. I added `intval()` function in the last edit. Also, I replaced hard-coded `3` in the equation with `count($colors)`. It will automaticaly put the number of colors held in the array.

Comment: thanks bro. its linking now. Hopefully it changes in 7 days times.

Comment: It will. Don't worry. If you don't believe, test it. For example add or subtract `(60 * 60 * 24 * 7)` to/from the `time()` function and see what the output will be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use date function to get current week of year and use modulo to choose proper color:

```
<?php
function color() {
  switch(date('W') %3 ) {
   case 0: return 'blue.css';
   case 1: return 'greeen.css';
   case 2: return 'yellow.css';
  }
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $filelocation->fetchdir($css) . color(); ?>
```

Comment: I tried this. I want to do a quick test to see if it works and change "w" to "S" but nothing change

Comment: This method has one disadvantage. When the week changes at the turn of the year, the modulo sequence crashes. E.g. last week in the year is 53. `53 % 3 == 2`, then new year starts with week 1, so `1 % 3 == 1`. In this particular day you go backwards with the color. __Moreover__, you have absolutely no guarantee that the new year starts on monday.

Comment: I dont really bother as long as it changes every 7 days... i DID `switch(time() / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7) % 12)` is correct? Bare in mine I have 12 different colors so I did a switch to `case 11`

Comment: Do `12` because you want to get modulo. E.g. `12 % 12` gives you `0` which is the first element in your array. Note that I also added `intval` for the whole equation.

Comment: And well, if you use the above answer, it won't change every 7 days. As I said before, at the turn of the year the _week of year_ changes. New Year's Eve can happen in the middle of the week.